# Can we get the hat frequencies?

Tags: discussion

I get the impression that the Darth Vader hat is the most popular. I can't imagine why, anyone would think that (a) physicists are all sci-fi geeks and (b) there's a new Star Wars film out.

Anyhow, is there a way to find the numbers of Physics SE members currently wearing each hat?

Comment: I'm not a sci-fi geek.

Comment: Oh well, never mind, we can't all be perfect.

Comment: We can log into [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), and then go to Physics S.E, but this would only give the hats earned by each Physics S.E user

Comment: Actually, from a quick scan of the [leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/physics.stackexchange.com), I think it is bested by the Sufganiyot hat. I assume they are popular since they are both day-specific hats which you can get simply through voting.

Comment: [A related feature request I asked a couple days ago on Meta Stack Exchange.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271005/is-there-a-way-to-find-who-earned-a-specific-hat-on-a-specific-site)